# native sqlite and room with same name , version , entites but need encription in my db using sqlite cipher

Tags: android, sqlite, roomdb, sqlite-cipher

im using native sqlite and room db with same name , version , entites so how can i encript this data base using sqlitecipher?

im dont encript the data bese using support factory for room and normal nativ sqlite encription but ints work for the first compile if i close and open or re compile the code its throw an erro like no such a data base

net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;

and
foundnet.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: UNIQUE constraint failed: table_name.field